# Encrypting a password column in a SQL database

Tags: php, sql

I have a column in my database name password, I just want to hash or encrypt the password before posting to the database. I have a code like this in my php submit file.

```
<?php
session_start();
include('config.php');

$ID=$_POST['ID'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$department=$_POST['department'];
$email=$_POST['email'];

$ID_arr=array();
$name_arr=array();
$password_arr=array();
$dept_arr=array();
$email_arr=array();

$i = -1;

++$i;
$ID_arr[$i]= $_POST['ID'];
$name_arr[$i]= $_POST['name'];
$password_arr[$i]= $_POST['password'];
$dept_arr[$i]= $_POST['department'];
$email_arr[$i]= $_POST['email'];

$j=0;
while ( $j <= $i)
{   
$ID = $ID_arr[$i];
$name = $name_arr[$i];
$password = $password_arr[$i];
$department = $dept_arr[$i];
$email = $email_arr[$i];

$sql = "INSERT INTO `employee`. `admin` (ID ,name ,password ,department
 ,email)         VALUES     (

  '$ID' ,'$name' ,'$password' ,'$department' ,'$email'
  )";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
if(!$result){
   die('invalid query:'.mysql_error());
 }
 else
echo ("<tr><td>" . "You have been succesfully registered..." . "</td></tr>");
header('Refresh:5; url=adminlogin.php');
die;
}
?>
```

May i know where should put the encrypt function? Or any way to encrypt the password?

Comment: Maybe something like this `$password=md5($_POST['password']);`

Comment: Better yet, see this (accepted) answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6782189/1415724

Comment: And here's another pretty good article, rather large but worth the read http://www.openwall.com/articles/PHP-Users-Passwords

Comment: Last one http://www.larryullman.com/forums/index.php?/topic/528-how-to-check-login-using-prepared-statement/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981638/php-password-encryption-handling

Answer (score 3):

You can use the MySQL [`PASSWORD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password) function and also PHP [`crypt`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) function.

An example of the MySQL function:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (PASSWORD('abcd'));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have PHP >= 5.5.0 then:

```
$password = password_hash('the password');
```

If you have an older version of PHP then use the [compatibility library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Include the `lib/password.php` file and then use [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php) as usual.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **forget md5**. If you use PHP >= 5.1.2 you are able to use [hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) function.

From the code you have regarded:

```
...
$j=0;
while ( $j <= $i)
{   
$ID = $ID_arr[$i];
$name = $name_arr[$i];
$password = $password_arr[$i];
$department = $dept_arr[$i];
$email = $email_arr[$i];
...
```

You just have to make the following to the $password:

```
$password = hash('sha256', $password_arr[$i]);
```

However, using sha256, you have to ensure that your password field in your database's table is 64 or more in length i,e varchar(64) or char(64). Look at the following question's answer as a guide:

- [When using a SHA256 hash, how long is the hash? (ie, how long should my mysql VARCHAR be?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240973/when-using-a-sha256-hash-how-long-is-the-hash-ie-how-long-should-my-mysql-va)

Also, in your config.php you may define a slat such as $salt, which will be a fixed string to be added to every password:

```
//in your config.php
...
$salt = 'jhfdkjdhfTyhdh3365@jdh69kkshhQAAAiyeg'// some ungussed string
...
// in your hash code:

 $password = hash('sha256', $salt.$password_arr[$i]);
```

Comment: thanks alot for your answer, i always get to solved my problem in this site, and friendly personalities you all have here, nice to meet you :)

Comment: Hi there, i am having problem in login time as the password entered not match with the hash password in database, hw can i rehash the entered password since it's already salt

Comment: By the same that you hashed it before saving in the database. Insert the hashed value in the select query of your database.

Answer (score -1):

If you password is a variable, try using something like this

```
$input=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
$password = md5($input);
```

And let your SQL be something like

```
UPDATE table SET password='$password';
```

untested code...

from the actual manual.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php

Comment: You should **never** use the MD5 algorithm to hash passwords. It has not been safe for years.