# Why do salts stop rainbow tables?

Tags: cryptography, salt, rainbowtable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does password salt help against a rainbow table attack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420843/how-does-password-salt-help-against-a-rainbow-table-attack)

Before you mention it, I already read [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566504/why-do-salts-make-dictionary-attacks-impossible) I didn't follow.

Here's my understand of salts/rainbow tables. Please correct me where I'm wrong.

1. User inputs raw `password`.
2. `password` is concatenated with `salt` to give `passwordsalt` or `saltpassword`.
3. `passwordsalt`/`saltpassword` is hashed to value `hash`.
4. Enter hacker.
5. Hacker employs rainbow tables to reverse `hash` into `passwordsalt`/`saltpassword`.
6. Hacker has in hands (example) the string`letmein1horse`.

Given `letmein1horse`, doesn't this simply mean that there are two options:

1. Password is `letmein1` and salt is `horse`.
2. Password is `horse` and salt is `letmein1`.

So you see why I'm confused. My understand is clearly flawed, because if this was how it worked, obviously salts would be useless.

OR: Is my understanding correct, and it's the whole iteration scheme that completely undoes this obvious weakness?

Comment: Rainbow tables are huge and very long to compute, if you prefix all your passwords with the same string 16-bytes string, you're almost certain that hackers won't have a rainbow table for it.

Comment: .....off-topic vote? Weird.

Comment: Weird? What's weird is not reading the FAQ and assuming that it is on topic. Just because it interests you as a programmer does not make it on topic. This is clearly a crypto question rather than a programming.

Comment: @GregS, then why do we even have a cryptography tag? And why are all the similar/identical questions on topic?

Comment: A rainbow-table is only profitable, if you can crack more than 1 password, otherwise brute-forcing is faster (why not stop if you found a match). If every password has a different salt, you can indeed build rainbow-tables, but every rainbow-table can be used only for one single password (salt).

Comment: @Aerovistae: There is a cryptography tag because somebody created one. The existence of a tag doesn't imply that every subject conceivably related to that tag is on topic. stackoverflow is for programming questions.

Comment: The column of related questions with thousands of views and hundreds of upvotes (few of which have any code) seem to disagree. And under the FAQ, I would say this easily falls under both "a software algorithm" and "software tools commonly used by programmers," as well as being a "practical, answerable problem that is unique to the programming profession." But enough of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rainbow tables can help you go from hashes, to short sequences with limited character sets. For example, a rainbow table might support all alphanumeric sequences less than 10 characters long.

A salt is much longer and uses a wider character set. If you use a 128-bit random salt, creating a rainbow table becomes physically intractable.

Comment: just truncate the 128 but  charchter either from left or from right and then create a rainbow table?

Answer (score 0):

An attacker would not be able to create a precomputed lookup table (i.e. a rainbow table) of hashed values (password + salt), because it would require a large computation for each salt. A simple dictionary attack is still very possible, although much slower since it cannot be precomputed. [source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29)